# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404(https://localhost:44300/node_modules/@angular/router//bundles/router.umd.js)

Tags: typescript, angular, asp.net-mvc-5

I created an simple app in Angular 2 Its works fine in VS Code when I Integrate the same app in My Asp.Net MVC 5 application It Shows following Errors I have no Clue what I am doing wrong.

### Image

[image]

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/forms": "0.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.7",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.3",

    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",

    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.12",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  }

}
```

### system.js

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app': '/app', // 'dist',
        '@angular': '/node_modules/@angular',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': '/node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        'rxjs': '/node_modules/rxjs'
    };
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    };
    var ngPackageNames = [
      'common',
      'compiler',
      'core',
      'forms',
      'http',
      'platform-browser',
      'platform-browser-dynamic',
      'router',
      'router-deprecated',
      'upgrade',
    ];
    // Individual files (~300 requests):
    function packIndex(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Bundled (~40 requests):
    function packUmd(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
    var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
    // Add package entries for angular packages
    ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };
    System.config(config);
})(this);
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/systemjs.config.js#L53

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add following line in system.js and errors gone.
`// No umd for router yet
  packages['@angular/router'] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };`